# Disable /sales/billing_agreement/

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-1.9, billing-agreements

How do you disable /sales/billing_agreement/ I have changed the xml file in the layout folder so it doesnt show up on the menus but the url is still active

I added comments around the following in the billing_agreement.xml

```
<action method="addLink" translate="label"><name>billing_agreements</name><path>sales/billing_agreement/</path><label>Billing Agreements</label></action>
```

Comment: show us the changes that you have made

Comment: I have edited my original post

Comment: if the menu not appearing, then how do you get the url ?

Comment: If someone manually goes to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the `Mage_Sales_Billing_AgreementController` and in the method `preDispatch` add this:

```
public function preDispatch() {
    $this->_redirect('no-route');
}
```